# TS1005 error, ','expected with simple .forEach loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, foreach

It has been a while since I touched TypeScript, so I have no idea what is wrong with this loop. Is there any reason that menuItems is not defined as it should be?

[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: You are inside `{ ... }` there - so an object key would be expected, not a method call?

Comment: You are not in JSX code, so the surrounding `{ ... }` are not required.

Comment: You can wrap your `{...}` with a Fragment also like `<>{...}</>`

Comment: aah thanks for correcting my stupid mistake guys!

Comment: always post actual code, instead of just screenshots (in cases like these, sharing both could be helpful, but generally, prefer code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here isn't a Typescript one, but a core JS issue. The code reads you're trying to return an object without a key.

However, simply removing the `{ ... }` as the comments suggest is not the proper solution, as `forEach` does not return a value.

Because of the hover pop-up, I can't really see what you're trying to do but if it's just `console.log()`, you don't need the return value either.

To loop through an array in ES6 and return values, you may want to look into using `.map()` or `.filter()` depending on your desired output. If you want only one item from the array returned, then you may want to look into `.reduce()` instead.